# How to hide dotted lines in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, user-interface

Qt. QTreeWidget. How to hide dotted lines?

Answer (score 6):

If this indeed is about the branches (the question is not very clear), then QTreeView (and thus QTreeWidget) has a special function to do just that (since Qt 4.2):

```
treeWidget->setRootIsDecorated(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the branch lines on the left of the tree, try setting a stylesheet as such :

```
treeWidget->setStyleSheet(QString("QTreeView::branch { border-image: none; }"));
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
treeWidget->setRowHidden(rowNumber,QModelIndex(),true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try strecthing the header with;

```
treeWidget->header()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

Comment: This must be `treeWidget->header()->setStretchLastSection(true)`